# In PHP (or any language), Can 2 bitmasks be merged while maintaining "identity" of orignal bits?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

This may be a really silly question, but it just crossed my mind and I thought it would be interesting to know for sure....

So here is the scenario:

Users have 3 options for each day of the week: AM, PM, and OFF. These are mutually exclusive choices, so there is no option to work both an AM and PM on same day.

So if I wanted to store their AM shifts and PM shifts as separate bitmasks, and User1 chooses the following:

```
 S    M   T   W   Th   F   Sa
 A    P   X   A   X    P   A
```

I would have the following:

```
 $shifts['User1']['AM'] = 73;  //  1001001
 $shifts['User1']['PM'] = 34;  //  0100010
```

Now, if I just wanted to know which days User1 worked, I could obviously just do:

```
 $shifts['User1']['All'] = $shifts['User1']['AM'] | $shifts['User1']['PM'];
```

Or even just:

```
 $shifts['User1']['All'] = $shifts['User1']['AM'] + $shifts['User1']['PM'];
```

But what if I wanted the final result to distinguish AM from PM, something to the effect of:

```
 $shifts['User1']['AM'] = A00A00A;
 $shifts['User1']['PM'] = 0P000P0;
```

So that the A's and P's are both considered set, but that

```
 A00A00A | 0P000P0 = AP0A0PA;
```

Is there a common way of doing this, or am I thinking about this totally wrong?

Comment: Two things come to mind: ternary, and plain old not using bitmasks for this type of task.

Comment: Oh, at the end of the day, I'm sure I'd either keep them separated or use some other logic to extrapolate, etc. But the image of the As and Ps jumped into my head and I thought it might be either one of those "no, fool, that's now how it works" or "duh, just change the radix", so I had to throw it out there to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent three states in a binary fashion you need 2 bits. For instance, you could say that:

> PM = 01
>
> AM = 10
>
> OFF = 00

So now you have this:

`A00A00A` translates to `10 00 00 10 00 00 10`

`0P000P0` translates to `00 01 00 00 00 01 00`

Applying bitwise OR operation:

```
10 00 00 10 00 00 10
00 01 00 00 00 01 00
--------------------
10 01 00 10 00 01 10
A  P  0  A  0  P  A
```

You get `AP0A0PA`, your desired result.

Comment: I almost hate to give you the answer, since I was hoping it would involve something more weird or sophisticated.  But how do I test if someone is working on Sunday? It could be either `01` or `10`. Do I just always check for if it's *NOT* `00`? I'm sure I'll figure it out, but any more obvious advice is welcome.

Comment: I guess you'd check it the same way as if you were only using one bit for each state. Any logic that would apply to the first case also applies to the second. Checking for NOT `00` is an option.

Comment: @Anthony: This is really good answer, more efficient. To check if someone is working on Sunday, you just need to do `$shifts | 0b11000000000000` (if Sunday is the first day on the list). Then you will get `0` if there was no shift on Sunday. (of course the code may not work, this is only to show you the way to check specific day)

Answer (score 1):

To write a literal value in binary use: `0b1001001`, or hex: `0x49`, instead of decimal: `73`.

The bitmap will only ever give you true or false, so there is no way to represent three values (AM, PM, X) by compressing two bitmaps into one.

I think you are thinking about this wrong (others may have a smarter solution that I can't think of though).  An array of characters A, P, X might be as good for this.  You can merge arrays (so it is not the same as a string).

Comment: I didn't want to use the binary literal notation (I started to but went back) because it's new and kind of awful looking (I think). I still don't know why hex is superior to decimal for notation.  But to your actual point, I think you're right. I was curious about XORing with non-matching/non-traditional digits as an idea, but once they are merged, I'm only able to use binary math to see working/not-working, so I'm left with strings or arrays (unless someone else here knows some amazing way to use bitwise in a base-n system).

Comment: Hex has the advantage that its base (i.e) each digit is worth exactly four digits of binary, so you can isolate each binary bit reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. See the example below in Python:

```
>>> class WorkShift(str):
    def __or__(self, val):
        def shift_calc(x, y):
            return x if x != '0' else y
        return WorkShift(''.join(map(shift_calc, self, val)))

>>> WorkShift('A00A00A') | WorkShift('0P000P0')
'AP0A0PA'
```

Does it answer your question?

Ps. I used Python since you explicitly stated it can be any programming language. I overloaded `|` operator. Result of the operation is still `WorkShift`'s instance, so you can use it for further processing. It also inherits from `str`, so you can use it as string as well.

**EDIT**:

Similar solution for PHP, but without operator overloading, based only on strings processing:

```
<?php

function shift_calc($x, $y) {
    return $x != '0' ? $x : $y;
};

function shift_sum($am, $pm) {
    return implode(array_map('shift_calc', str_split($am), str_split($pm)));
};

$result = shift_sum('A00A00A', '0P000P0');
```

where the `$result` is a string with the following value: "`AP0A0PA`" (see proof here: http://ideone.com/NbTEJ).

Comment: +1 for showing it *can* be done. Now I just have to get out my reverse-engineer cap to figure out if it can be replicated in PHP.

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, it can be implemented. See the example for PHP < 5.3 (for PHP >= 5.3 it would be even nicer): http://ideone.com/NbTEJ

Comment: Let me copy that over to my local server and see if I can figure out how to get it nicer in 5.3 (or I'll never learn!).

Answer (score 1):

minitech's comment is correct.  This is a ternary number system (because you have 3 choices for each value).  So you could do this:

```
$shifts['User1']['AM'] = '1001001';  //  A00A00A
$shifts['User1']['PM'] = '0200020';  //  0P000P0

$all = intval($shifts['User1']['AM'], 3) +
    intval($shifts['User1']['PM'], 3);

echo base_convert($all, 10, 3);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind! (sorta) I wasn't sure if you could just change the radix and still get the same positional result. Does this work to the nth radix (or as high as `intval()` and `base_convert` will allow)?  If so, it seems like you just take the number of choices, multiply each bit set by it's "row number" and then add them all using the total count, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. Interleave

   The original bitmask is spread out, and the new bitmask is inserted in the new "holes".

   > ```
   > APAPAPAPAPAPAP
   > ```
2. Append

   The new bitmask is appended to the old bitmask.

   > ```
   > AAAAAAAPPPPPPP
   > ```

The former is easier to inspect/compare, but the latter is more efficient with regards to speed.

Comment: Well that took some wikipeida reading to swallow.  It's not clear to me, though, where the 0s went.  How do I spread out the "holes" on the other side? (very possible I'm missing the actual point).

Comment: The As and Ps are not *literal* As and Ps; it would not be a bitmask if they were. Rather, they represent where the 0s and 1s go. Making the holes is not a trivial process. This is why appending is more efficient.

Comment: Ha! I know they aren't literal, or I'd just be a total fool for asking the question in the first place.  I just think the core idea is over my head (for now).  But I'm glad the holes aren't trivial. I thought I was missing something really basic.